# I need OpenGL ES 1.1 to render objects with texturing and others with just vertex paints and colors simple

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, opengl-es, texturing

I'm running on XCode and using OpenGL ES 1.1 and I have two classes one that is textured and the other one is just triangles with color data and they render fine until I render my textured triangles that work but then the others also become textured with odd parts of my sprite atlas and they dont have any texture coord's at all

```
-(void) renderWithUpdate {

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

//Translate
glTranslatef(tranlation.x, tranlation.y, tranlation.z);

//Scale
glScalef(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);

//Rotate
glRotatef( angleGeo, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);


angleGeo = angleGeo + 0.5;
//NSLog(@"Rotation Angle:%F", (float)angleGeo );

glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vertexes );
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.colors);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);                


//Render with Texturing 
if (materialKey != nil) {

    [[MaterialController  sharedMaterialController] bindMaterial:materialKey];

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvCoordinates);

}


//Render
glDrawArrays( renderStyle, 0, self.vertexCount);
}
```

and if I disable texture corded arrays in their rendering method they vanish completly all wile my textured objets work fine

is it something to do with `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rendering the textured objects you have to disable texturing by calling `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` (I guess your `MaterialController`'s `bindMaterial` method calls `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`). Just disabling the texture coordinate array (with `glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)`) is not enough (though you should do this, too, after rendering the textured geometry):

```
...
glDrawArrays( renderStyle, 0, self.vertexCount);

if(materialKey != nil)
{
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Always keep in mind, that **OpenGL is a state machine** and every state you change (like enabling texturing) keeps its value until **you** change it again. So you should always be aware what parts of your application change what OpenGL states (like the `bindMaterial` method) and set every state you need immediately before rendering.

Comment: @user994423 If the answer was the solution to your problem, [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) would be appreciated.